# Omnet++/INET: parameter added to cMessage becomes 0 when received

Tags: simulation, omnet++, inet

In our simulation we added two fields to cMessage class as protected:

```
/* sequence number for log files */
long seqNo = 0;

/* timestamp at sending message */
simtime_t sendingTime;
```

and we add the following publics methods

```
public:

  void setSeqNo(long n) {
    this->seqNo = n;
  }

  long getSeqNo() {
    return this->seqNo;
  }

  void setSentTime(simtime_t t) {
    this->sendingTime = t;
  }

  simtime_t getSentTime() {
    return this->sendingTime;
  }
```

Now, when the server simulated application runs, before each message seding it performs:

```
pkt->setSeqNo(numPkSent);
pkt->setSentTime(simTime());
fprintf(this->analyticsCorrespondentNode, "PKT %u SENT AT TIME %f TO NODE %s \n", numPkSent, pkt->getSentTime().dbl(), d->clientAddr.get4().str().c_str());
```

On the other hand, when the message is received by the simulated application client if performs:

```
double recvTime = simTime().dbl();
fprintf(this->analyticsMobileNode, "RECEIVED PKT num. %d SENT AT TIME: %f RECEIVED AT TIME %f TRANSMISSION TIME ELAPSED %f \n", msg->getSeqNo(), msg->getSentTime().dbl(), recvTime, recvTime - msg->getSentTime().dbl());
```

The problem is that SeqNo is correctly written by the client as it had been set by the server before sending. Instead, the methods

```
msg->getSentTime.dbl()
```

always returns 0 in the client log file while it is correctly set by the server in the server log file. I don't understand why, maybe there's something strange happening in the conversion between cMessage to cPacket in the client application...do you know this?

Answer (score 2):

In order to add own fields to a packet definition you should **only** prepare the definition in `*.msg` file. For example file `FooPacket.msg`:

```
packet FooPacket {
   long       seqNo;
   simtime_t sendingTime;
   // other fields... 
 }
```

Then, in your source file `*.cc` add: 
`#include "FooPacket_m.h"`  
The class `FooPacket` which derives from `cPacket` as well as all setter and getter methods **will be generated automatically** during the compilation - you will see the following files: `FooPacket_m.h` and `FooPacket_m.cc`.  
When your client receives a message, you should check whether the type is the same as you expected and then cast it to `FooPacket` type. For example this way:

```
void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) {
   if (dynamic_cast<FooPacket* >(msg)) {
      FooPacket *pkt = check_and_cast<FooPacket* >(msg);
      simtime_t t = pkt->getSendingTime();
   }
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be the conversion from cMessage to cPacket. Have you tried this?

```
Packet pk = check_and_cast<Packet *>(msg);
pk->getSentTime.dbl();
```

Also you can try to check if there is a problem with `simtime_t double` somewhere, try `double` for `sentTime` parameter

Comment: Yes, I had already tried to call .dbl() before as you suggest but nothing changed. I think I will try to read the simTime before the cMessage is casted to cPacket, in other words before PK() macro is called on cMessage (which contains the instruction check_and_cas you've mentioned)